# Use a checkbox state to set the binding source for another control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Is there a simple and elegant way in WPF to set the data binding source of a control using the value of another control ?

For example, I have a `ListBox` displaying a set of data, and when a `Checkbox` is checked I want to use another set of data (like a filtered data set for example).

I can figure out that I could bind the `Checkbox` to a `bool` property, and work in the getter of the data source property so that it returns one or another set depending on the `bool` value. But I am looking for even more elegant if it is possible.

Comment: @All who answered : Thanks a lot for all the answers !! Finally I have worked out what I wanted using the MultipleBinding solution from Krzysztof Bracha. I have even put the ItemsSource inside the multiple binding block and use the converter to to set the output list depending on the checkbox state. It gives a simple and elegant solution (up to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your `ListBox.ItemsSource` property to `CheckBox.IsChecked` property and use `ValueConveter` to check the state and return appropriate items.

In this example I use `MultiValueConveter` to allow to select items from a model bound to `Window` element.

**Edit**: Included an example way of providing `ItemSource` notifications.

Declare converter in `Window.Resources`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IsCheckedConverter x:Key="isCheckedConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Create `XAML` code:

```
<CheckBox Name="CheckBox" />
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource isCheckedConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="CheckBox" Path="IsChecked"/>
            <Binding Path="MyModel.MyLists" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

Create `Window`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyModel = new MyModel();
    }
}
```

Create conveter:

```
public class IsCheckedConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isChecked = (bool)values[0];
        List<string>[] lists = (List<string>[])values[1];

        if (isChecked == true)
        {
            return lists[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return lists[1];
        }

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }  
}
```

Example model implementation:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public List<string>[] MyLists { get; set; }

    public MyModel()
    {
        MyLists = new List<string>[2];

        MyLists[0] = new List<string>() { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
        MyLists[1] = new List<string>() { "123", "456", "789" };
    }

    public void UpdateListsExample()
    {
        MyLists[0] = new List<string>() { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" };
        MyLists[1] = new List<string>() { "123", "456" };
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyLists");
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Binding to the MyModel object has one small shortcoming, that connected with the fact that if the ListA or ListB properties are changed, the ItemsSource property Binding won't be notified about these changes. Perhaps, it makes sense to bind directly to the ListA and ListB properties.

Comment: As the lists are members of a model it makes sense to update them not directly but through the model. The model can then implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: The point is that even if your view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, the binding won't be updated if the bound property is not in the Binding's path

Comment: This is true, I have updated my answer to allow for list change notifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to accomplish this task in XAML, you can create **DataTrigger** that binds to the **CheckBox.IsChecked** property and sets **ItemsSource**:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="listBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source1}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag.IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source2}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="checkBox"/>
    <ListBox Margin="0,20,0,0" Tag="{Binding ElementName=checkBox}" Style="{StaticResource listBoxStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can figure out that I could bind the Checkbox to a bool property, and work in the getter of the data source property so that it returns one or another set depending on the bool value. But I am looking for even more elegant if it is possible.

Well, this is an elegant solution in my opinion :)

@Alex Russkov suggestions is a good alternative. Please note that you need to bind the `Tag` property of the `ListBox` to the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` (and not to the `CheckBox` itself) for the `ItemsSource` property to get updated as you check/uncheck the `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ckh" Content="Check Box..."/>
<ListBox Tag="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=ckh}">
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SourceCollectionA}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SourceCollectionB}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: In fact, if DataTrigger is bound to the Tag.IsChecked property, the approach with storing a reference to the entire CheckBox should also work. However, I agree that with your solution, the binding looks simpler :)

Answer (score -1):

You can define a property in the binding of the checkbox

```
<CheckBox Name="myCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Change}" />
```

And then in the viewmodel to handle the true / false condition of the checkbox

```
private bool isCheckedChange = false;

public bool Change {
   get { return isCheckedChange; }
   set {
       if (isCheckedChange)
       {
           MyListBocValue = new List<string> { "String1", "String2" };
       }else{
           MyListBocValue = new List<string> { "String3", "String4" };
       }
    }
 }

public List<String> MyListBocValue { get; set; }
```